# How to setup an Ethernet bridge under macOS Sonoma 14.2.1?

Tags: networking, macos, bridge, ifconfig, bridging

When configuring an Ethernet Bridge under macOS Sonoma, it seems that the bridge will not be set up entirely.

From [another post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/707160/ifconfig-bridge-on-macos-brdgadd-en0-resource-busy) I learned that new devices should be configured via the GUI what I did. so I added a virtual device, I chose bridge, assigned the physical Ethernet adapter to the bridge and thought that it would be fine. Furthermore, the GUI showed a green light for an active bridge.

However, this bridge device did not receive an IP address via DHCP and also manually assigning a (different) IP address did not resolve connectivity issues.

Therefore, I opened zsh and tried to find out what is going on:

```
admin@mac % ifconfig

en0: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
options=50b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV,CHANNEL_IO>
ether <MyMacAddress goes here>
nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex,flow-control,energy-efficient-ethernet>)
status: active

bridge1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
ether <MyMacAddress goes here>
Configuration:
    id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
    maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
    root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
    ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
media: <unknown type>
status: inactive
```

However, when comparing my bridge1 as shown above with bridges set up by other applications, I realized that those look quite differently:

```
bridge103: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
ether <MyMacAddress goes here>
Configuration:
    id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
    maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
    root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
    ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
member: en0 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
        ifmaxaddr 0 port 4 priority 0 path cost 0
member: vmenet3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
        ifmaxaddr 0 port 24 priority 0 path cost 0
member: vmenet4 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
        ifmaxaddr 0 port 28 priority 0 path cost 0
media: autoselect
status: active
```

When setting up my bridge1 in the GUI, I ticked the Ethernet adapter, but it is not shown as an added member - and bridge1 did not get activated. I tried adding "en0" manually but failed:

```
admin@mac % sudo ifconfig bridge1 addm en0
ifconfig: BRDGADD en0: Resource busy
```

Does anybody has a hint as how to proceed further?